# Search with Pymongo, using KeyWords, REGEX and Array

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to find a way more 'smarter' to make a SEARCH with MongoDB using Regex. I'm retaliative new on MongoDB and i struggling to make this work's fine, i already develop a solution but it's slow asf because i keep open new connection on every single loop.

I will show example SCHEMA and the Solution i develop for easily understanding.

Example SCHEMA:

```
stocks = {
    {'name': 'Microsoft',
     'ticker': 'MSFT'},
}

news = {
    {'title': 'News highs on MSF this Week',
     'text': 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.'},
    
    {'title': 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text',
     'text': 'Microsoft get news High every month on last few quartelys.'},
    
    {'title': 'New user on Facebook',
     'text': 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.'},
    
    {'title': 'Any single text',
     'text': 'New records on FB this month...'},
    
    {'title': 'Anohter random title',
     'text': 'And another random Text'},
    
}
```

First i get the keywords im looking for into a ARRAY:

```
key_words = []
raw_db = news.find({'name': 'Microsoft'})

name_stock = raw_db.get('name')
ticker_stock = raw_db.get('ticker')

key_words.append(name_stock)
ticker_stock.append(ticker_stock)
```

In this case will be: ['MSFT', 'Microsoft'] and now start making the query over this keywords.

```
""" Parse Key Words with REGEX """
    
kw_result = []

for _kw in key_words:
    title = {'title': {'$regex': _kw, '$options': 'i'}}
    text = {'text': {'$regex': _kw, '$options': 'i'}}

    # Query Title and append result to KW_RESULT array
    find_title = news.find(title)
    
    for _title in find_title:
        kw_result.append(_title)

    # Query TEXT and append result to KW_RESULT array
    find_text = news.find(text)

    for _text in find_title:
        kw_result.append(_text)
```

Output will be:

```
kw_result = {[

    {'title': 'News highs on MSF this Week',
     'text': 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.'},
    
    {'title': 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text',
     'text': 'Microsoft get news High every month on last few quartelys.'},
]}
```

Has i said on begin this solution works fine, but it's very slow when u start making query over tons of documentations. Any suggestion how i can improve this query system, i already saw the DOC from MongoDb and don't found any section talking about REGEX and Array.

Regards Cid.

Comment: you want search in `item` and `text` ?
another thing you want to return match element of array or whole doc ?

Comment: and news is your collection , or is a field as array ?